# Where should my images go in Rails? What does precompile do exactly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 3 with assets pipeline enabled.

And I know images such as icons or logos should go in app/assets/images.

But where should I put images that may be a lot and big? For example images uploaded by the users, such as photos

I don't want them to be duplicated by precompile (not sure if it does that, I don't know how it works). And I want them to be ready to use as soon as they get uploaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image_tag wasn't working as expected. In the documentation it says 'By default, files are loaded from public/images', but that wasn't working.

The solution was to add /images to the path (with leading backslash, or it won't work)

```
<%= image_tag '/images/some_dir/some_image.jpeg' %>
```

Comment: Where did you read that in the documentation? And what was your exact solution by "Adding /images to the path"?

Comment: @ryan-bigg http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html 3.1.4. I mean instead of 'some_dir/some_image.jpeg' or '/some_dir/some_image.jpeg', I had to use '/images/some_dir/some_image.jpeg'.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is a great, inexpensive way to store images that your users upload. I recommend using the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) which integrates with s3. There's a section in the [paperclip documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) with instructions on how to use s3. No clue what precompiling images means or how it applies to uploaded image files, but they will be available as soon the upload is complete. Using this also has some additional benefits such as acting as a backup system.

Comment: In production, images inside app/assets can't be used unless you precompile them (or change the config to be a little more like development enviroment). And thanks for recommending s3 but I have my own servers, I just need to know where is the best place to put the images. I tried dropping them in public/images but didn't work

Comment: @HappyDeveloper I know this is some years ago when you posted that, but I would like to ask you if you continue to use your server to upload images ? I don't like very much the idea of storing images on S3 and I would like to know if there is a scalable way to do that with my own server ? thanks